# Search through COUNT(*)

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get all names of people with their number of skill for every person! So everything is fine but the problem is how to search for a person who's got '2' skills for example?

```
SELECT FULLNAME, TeamNAME, COUNT(*) AS NoSkills 
FROM [Skills Matrix].[dbo].[PeopleSkills] AS PS, [Skills Matrix].[dbo].[People] AS P, [Skills Matrix].[dbo].[Teams] AS T
WHERE PS.FK_People = P.ID AND P.FK_TEAM = T.ID AND NoSkills LIKE '2'
GROUP BY FULLNAME, TeamNAME, NoSkills
```

This output I've got:

[image]

Could you help me please!

Comment: NoSkills is not a column of our table. Please post your table structure

Comment: I believe you need `COUNT(*) = 2` because MSSQL does not allow referencing of aliased columns in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GROUP BY FULLNAME, TeamNAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not group by the alias that you create in the select list. Remove `NoSkills` from `GROUP BY`. Also, if you want to filter the aggregated functions' values (e.g. `COUNT`), you should use `HAVING` clause (not `WHERE`).

```
SELECT FULLNAME, TeamNAME, COUNT(*) AS NoSkills 
FROM [Skills Matrix].[dbo].[PeopleSkills] AS PS, [Skills Matrix].[dbo].[People] AS P, [Skills Matrix].[dbo].[Teams] AS T
WHERE PS.FK_People = P.ID AND P.FK_TEAM = T.ID
GROUP BY FULLNAME, TeamNAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **NoSkills** from group by clause.